# LOCK=NONE when adding NOT NULL constraint fails with "cannot silently convert NULL values" error despite no NULL values being present

Tags: mysql, innodb, ddl

I'm trying to use MySQL's [online DDL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) feature to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to an InnoDB table without blocking writes to the table. According to manual, this should be possible - the linked table summarising MySQL 5.6's online DDL capabilities has a 'YES' in the ***Allows concurrent DML*** column of the ***Make column NOT NULL*** row.

However, when I actually try this, it fails under absolutely all circumstances I've tried. Even if the column I'm trying to add the `NOT NULL` constraint to does not contain any `NULL` values, I get the following strange error:

> ERROR 1846 (0A000): LOCK=NONE is not supported. Reason: cannot silently convert NULL values, as required in this SQL_MODE. Try LOCK=SHARED.

Here's an ultra-simple test case at the MySQL shell:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `Test` (
    ->   `id` int(10) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `stuff` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
mysql> ALTER TABLE Test MODIFY stuff varchar(100) NOT NULL, LOCK=none;
ERROR 1846 (0A000): LOCK=NONE is not supported. Reason: cannot silently convert NULL values, as required in this SQL_MODE. Try LOCK=SHARED.
```

How (if at all) can I get around this and add a `NOT NULL` constraint while permitting concurrent DML?

In case it's relevant: my exact MySQL version is 5.6.16 and my SQL_MODE is `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ad20) (version 5.6.6) does not show any errors. Which version exactly do you have? And what is the `SQL_MODE`?

Comment: @ypercube Hmm, weird. Version is 5.6.16 and `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode` and `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode` give me `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: And the table is empty, right? Weird.

Comment: @ypercube Yep, empty table - the test case above I executed in a newly-created database and then copied directly out of my terminal. (Also note that the same error happens if I first insert some rows without nulls in the relevant column, and happens on my live database on a ~20-million-row table with no NULLs. The failure is not limited to the special case where the table is empty.)

Comment: Well, the error reason 1846 was added at 5.6.10. That explains why SQL-Fiddle does not show it. I guess you have to wait for someone who knows more details - you can also raise an issue/bug at the official MySQL site or search if there is already something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that was introduced in MySQL 5.6.10 and has since been fixed (although there is no bug report on http://bugs.mysql.com that I can find). The behaviour described in the question does not occur in the latest version of MySQL.

Observed behaviour in MySQL 5.7.5-m15:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `Test` (
    ->   `id` int(10) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `stuff` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE Test MODIFY stuff varchar(100) NOT NULL, LOCK=none;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.97 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```